# Permissions not work in Android studio

Tags: java, android, permissions, manifest

I imported an old eclipse adt project into android studio; it's a simple client that open a socket toward a local server but when i run it, android studio generate a "Java.net.SocketException permission denied".
I'm sure that the code works because from eclipse it works. So there is a method can I use to refresh the manifest or to say to android studio to update it ? 
I tried to do a clean project but nothing.

My manifest file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.client" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

instead of:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

There's no permission named

```
ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET
```

there however one named that way:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Comment: I believe they aren't case sensitive, so it should make no difference. Although you are right in pointing out the correct convention.

Comment: It's case sensitive instead ! He is right. Thanks a lot @Marcin Orlowski

Comment: Strange, I have tested this on Android Studio and it works in either upper/lowercase for me.

Comment: yes, it is strange, I also thought it was case insensitive